# Remove duplicate elements from list in Tcl

Tags: tcl

How to remove duplicate element from Tcl list say:

```
list is like [this,that,when,what,when,how]
```

I have Googled and have found `lsort unique` but same is not working for me. I want to remove when from list.

Comment: What do you call a "list"?

Comment: @user2901871, you have asked many Tcl questions where you do not show that you understand Tcl syntax. The Tcl tutorial will help you quite a bit: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html

Answer (score 13):

The following works for me

```
set myList [list this that when what when how]
lsort -unique $myList
```

this returns

```
how that this what when
```

which you could store in a new list

```
set uniqueList [lsort -unique $myList]
```

Comment: This one will change the order of the original list

Answer (score 9):

You could also use an dictionary, where the keys must be unique:

```
set l {this that when what when how}
foreach element $l {dict set tmp $element 1}
set unique [dict keys $tmp]
puts $unique
```

```
this that when what how
```

That will preserve the order of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

glenn jackman's answer work perfectly on **Tcl 8.6** and above.

For **Tcl 8.4** and below (No dict command). You can use:

```
proc list_unique {list} {
    array set included_arr [list]
    set unique_list [list]
    foreach item $list {
        if { ![info exists included_arr($item)] } {
            set included_arr($item) ""
            lappend unique_list $item
        }
    }
    unset included_arr
    return $unique_list
}

set list   [list this that when what when how]
set unique [list_unique $list]
```

This will also preserve the order of the elements
and this is the result:

**this that when what how**

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if do not wanna use native lsort function.This is what the interviewer asks :)

```
`set a "this that when what when how"
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $a]} {incr i} {
    set indices [lsearch -all $a [lindex $a $i]]
    foreach index $indices {
        if {$index != $i} {
            set a [lreplace $a $index $index]
        }
    }
}
```

`